# Necessary and Sufficient Conditions for the pair of integers $\{m,n\}$ to generate $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers

Let $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ be two non zero numbers. I need to find necessary and sufficient conditions on $m$ and $n$ for which the pair $\{m,n\}$ generates the additive group $\mathbb{Z}$.

I made an attempt at a proof, and would like to know if 1) It's correct, and 2) if there's anything I can do to make it better.

First of all, I asserted that **a necessary and sufficient condition would be for $\mathbf{\gcd(m,n)=1}$**.

Now, here's my proof:

> $(\implies)$ Suppose that $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Then, by Bezout's Identity, $\exists$ integers $p,q$ such that $mp+nq = \gcd(m,n)=1$.
>
> Let $k$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then, we can produce $k$ by multiplying both sides of $mp+nq = 1$ through by $k$ to yield $m(pk)+n(qk)=k$.
>
> Defining $x=pk \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $y = qk \in \mathbb{Z}$, we see that $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\exists x, y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $mx+ny=k$.
>
> So, $<m,n>=\mathbb{Z}$.
>
> $(\Longleftarrow)$ Suppose $<m,n>=\mathbb{Z}$. Then, $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\exists x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $k=mx+ny$.
>
> Therefore, we must have $\gcd(m,n)|k$.
>
> (**The part I'm really not sure about)** However, $k$ is an arbitrary integer, and thee only integer that is a divisor of any arbitrary integer is $1$.
>
> Thus, $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof of the first direction looks perfectly fine. Your proof of the second part is definitely on the right track, and as it stands it's not *wrong*, but it's a little unclear. Somewhat better is to note that, since $\gcd(m,n)$ divides $k$ for every integer $k$, it divides $1$ in particular. Knowing that $\gcd(m,n)$ divides $1$, you get $\gcd(m,n)=1$. That is, you can just immediately take $x$ and $y$ such that $mx+ny=1$ and  conclude from there that they are coprime.

Comment: thank you for that! That is a much clearer way of saying what I was trying to say. I hope you get your radian in mathematics, by the way ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your proof of sufficiency was right. Thus, we are going to focus on the part of necessity.

The first thing is that your unsure part is right. It has right logic.

Another proof I am going to give is that, as $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$, $m\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}=gcd(m,n)\mathbb{Z}$.

As $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID and $m\mathbb{Z}, n\mathbb{Z}$ are ideals, $m\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}$ must be a principal ideal, say $d\mathbb{Z}$.

As $m,n\in d\mathbb{Z}$, $d|m$ and $d|n$.

Also, as $d\in d\mathbb{Z}$, $d=mr+ns$, but $\forall e$ such that $e|m, e|n$, $e$ must divide $d$.

Thus $d=gcd(m,n)$.

In this case, you can see that $gcd(m,n)=1$ because $m\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: what does PID stand for?

Comment: @JessyCat Principle ideal domain, an algebraic structure in ring theory. I thought providing a view from abstract algebra would be helpful, since other answers are not answering using techniques from this subject.

Comment: I suppose it does. We haven't gotten to ring theory yet, though.

Comment: @JessyCat Sure. However, this still holds in group theory in a way that all subgroups of integers, like {m,n}, can be generated by one element, which is gcd(m,n). You can start by proving this one, which requires no knowledge of ring theory.

Answer (score 2):

You have that, for $k+1\in\mathbb{Z}$ exist $x',y'\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $mx'+ny'=k+1$ you can use $mx'+ny'-(mx+ny)=k+1-k=1$ thus $m(x'-x)+n(y-y')=1$ then you have $gcd(m,n)=1$.